# VBA: Error handling with labels and "On Error GoTo"

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have multiple procedures that look like the one below. The code itself is functional and does what it is supposed to do, but now I have one question and one problem regarding error handling:

1. How to use `On Error GoTo 0`:

The error which is causing me trouble occurrs in the line `mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`. It's my understanding that `On Error GoTo 0` resets the error handling to the default behavior in VBA, meaning I should get the error displayed in the normal VBA-way. So I used it twice here: once directly after the line with which I paste what I copied and once directly after calling the `ErrorHandler1` (and 2). Does this make sense? My reasoning was that with `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1` I only want to trap error `-2147188160` and in the rest of the code I want the normal VBA error messages. Errors aren't that likely to occur there because there isn't a lot of code, but still.

```
 Sub SubSlide1(wsKAP As Worksheet)

    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(1)

RepeatOnError1:  
    Set rng = wsKAP.Range("AC2:AN29")
    rng.Copy
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 20
        .Top = 48
        .Width = 623
    End With

RepeatOnError2:
    wsKAP.Columns("K:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rng = wsKAP.Range("A187:V199")
    rng.Copy
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
    With myShape
        .Left = 20
        .Top = 363
        .Width = 663
    End With
    wsKAP.Columns("K:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler1:
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
        Call ErrorHandling(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Fehler: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Makro wird weiter ausgeführt."
    End If
    Resume RepeatOnError1

ErrorHandler2:
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
        Call ErrorHandling(2)
    Else
        MsgBox "Fehler: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Makro wird weiter ausgeführt."
    End If
    Resume RepeatOnError2
End Sub


Sub ErrorHandling(Number As Long)
    If ErrorCount(Number) > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Too many errors (-2147188160) in ErrorCount(" & Number & "). Canceling."
        End
    End If

    ErrorCount(Number) = ErrorCount(Number) + 1
    Debug.Print "ErrorCount" & Number & " is " & ErrorCount(Number)
End Sub
```

2. Sometimes when I run my code a MsgBox pops up: "Error: 0. Procedure will continue." (this has occured in the procedure you see here as well as in the other procedures, which are structurally the same). This means the else-statement in `ErrorHandler1` gets triggered. My intention with the `else` was to let me know about any error that gets caught up in `GoTo ErrorHandler1`, but isn't `-2147188160`. As far as I know "Error 0" means there isn't an error, so how does VBA end up there?

**edit:** I've rearranged it now and added an `End`. I moved the `Resume` statement because otherwise I have the potential of an endless-error loop.

```
ErrorHandler1:

    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
        Call ErrorHandling(1)
        Resume RepeatOnError1
    Else
        MsgBox "Fehler: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Makro wird weiter ausgeführt."
        End
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

ErrorHandler2:

    If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
        Call ErrorHandling(2)
        Resume RepeatOnError2
    Else
        MsgBox "Fehler: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Makro wird weiter ausgeführt."
        End
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: While the below answer does explain why your `Err.Number` checks aren't working when they're done after `On Error GoTo 0`, I would strongly recommend breaking down your code into smaller, more specialized procedures that do fewer things and, ideally, have *one* reason to fail. These `GoTo`, and `Resume` jumps make things hard to follow - also execution is falling through to `RepeatOnError2` from `RepeatOnError1`, is that intentional?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon What do you mean falls through?  When #1 fails, it should repeat. After it successful, it is supposed to continue with what comes under `RepeatOnError2`. Is that what you mean? As for using  more specialized subs: would you suggest splitting this one in two? Regarding the confusion stemming from `GoTo` and `Resume`: I agree, but I didn't come up with an alternative way.

Comment: I mean well-structured code that's easy to follow would normally have a single error handler, if any. An error handler subroutine should only run when execution is in an error state, i.e. there's a clean separation between the "happy path" and the "error path", which isn't happening with Error1 clearing errors and falling through into Error2.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon So let's say the whole section under `RepeatOnError2` wasn't there (except `ErrorHandler1`): would my code be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> On Error GoTo 0
> If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
> ```

On Error Go To 0 also "clears" any current error. So you are clearing it before checking if it is equal to -2147188160. Re-arrange those statements and see if that works better:

```
If Err.Number = -2147188160 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I put it below the whole if statement (i.e. after `end if`) because in the `else` part I still require the error number, but yes, that solved it. I also moved the `Resume`statement (see edit). Anyway, thank you!